# What items are only available once?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I noticed that the item Metal Cloak is only available once per game/save state and that means you can only evolve a single Scizor or Steelix. Now are there some other items that occur only once per game and that don't require you to steal it from a wild Pokemon to get a second one?

Comment: Are you not counting items that can be stolen from wild pokemon? Because Metal Coat can be, as can most others: http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/metalcoat.shtml

Comment: hmm okay I usually look it up in the German wiki since I play the game in German and there the stealing method is only listed for older generations. http://www.pokewiki.de/Entwicklung_(Tragen)#Metallmantel

Answer (score 1):

The items you mean are Evolution-inducing held items. These are often only avalible once in a game. Here is a list: [Evolution-inducing held items](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Evolution-inducing_held_item)

Also there are story and basic items you only get once like a bike and so on.

Which Pokémon evolve while holding an item you can see here:

[Evolution while hold an item](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Category:Pok%C3%A9mon_that_evolve_by_leveling_up_with_a_held_item)

[Evolution while trade and most of them hold an item](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Category:Pok%C3%A9mon_that_evolve_through_trading)